# How do I make my discord bot stay online

Tags: python, discord.py

I recently made a music bot in my discord server but the problem I have is that I have to turn on the bot manually etc. and it goes offline when I turn off my computer. How can I make the bot stay online at all times, even when I'm offline?

Comment: The bot is running from your computer. It's just a program, so *of course* it's going to go offline when your computer does. I have a Discord bot that runs on my Raspberry Pi. I recommend that solution for 24/7 botting.

Comment: I was wondering about this because I saw a server where everyone was offline but the bots were online so I thought that there may be a way. thanks for answering my question

Comment: Your bot needs to run somewhere. It could be on a separate piece of hardware you leave on, or you could buy time on a server somewhere "in the cloud" (which is just a fancy buzzword for describing a data center somewhere). Or, you know, you could just leave your PC on overnight.

Comment: There are many different options, some recommended ones are https://www.digitalocean.com/  --- https://www.ovh.com/us/ --- https://www.vultr.com/

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the python script on a server, e.g. an EWS linux instance.

To do that you would need to install python on the server and place the script in the home directory and just run it via a screen.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Raspberry Pi with an internet connection. Install all necessary components and then run the script in its terminal. Then, you can switch off the monitor and the bot will continue running. I recommend that solution to run the bot 24/7. If you don't have a Raspberry Pi, buy one (they're quite cheap), or buy a server to run the code on.